# Question about balls and empty bags

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

I did this exercise after studying this theory in a book. Is my reasoning correct?

> There are $210$ indistinguishable balls to distribute to $20$ distinct bags, staying exactly $7$ empty bags. How many different ways can the balls be distributed?

The set $B$ of balls is the domain and the set $C$ of bags is the range. Every function in $C^B$ describes a different one of the ways to put balls into bags. Since $7$ are to remain empty  we are interested in functions $f$ with $|Image(f)| = 13$.

So the answer should be $S(210,13) \frac{20!}{(20-13)!}$ , where $S$ represents the Stirling number of second kind.

Comment: To check your reasoning, it would be best to say separately  why you picked each of the factors.

Comment: I meant to ask if this is the right solution. If the solution is incorrect obviously my reasoning is also wrong.

Comment: Stirling numbers of the second kind enumerate *distinct balls* in *indistinguishable bags*. This problem on the other hand is about *indistinguishable balls* in *distinct bags* and can be solved using stars and bars. 210 balls go in *exactly* 13 bags with at least 1 ball in each in $\binom{210-1}{12}$ ways and those 13 bags can be selected from 20 in $\binom{20}{13}$ ways. Giving a count: $\binom{209}{12}\binom{20}{13}$.

Comment: @N.Shales Thanks for the answer. I can also use stirling numbers like I did when the balls are distinct and the bags are also distinct , right?

Comment: Yes that's right, although you need to multiply by a factor. Since $S(n,k)$ counts the ways of putting $n$ *distinct* balls into $k$  *indistinguishable* bags such that none are empty, then each one of these outcomes can have the $k$ bags labelled (made distinct) in $k!$ ways. So there are $k!S(n,k)$ ways of putting $n$ *distinct* balls into $k$ *distinct* bags such that none are empty. Also you may see $S(n,k)$ written $\smash{{n \brace k}}$.

Comment: In fact, what you did was perfectly correct for distinct balls *and* bags. I see you *did* multiply by $13!$, good work!